# How to subsruct the right side of a string that has dynamic length

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a string that I would like to get only the chars of the right side (after the dots to its left).In this example: `"SgY:ghhh"` 
The last string is of changing number of characters and the number of dots to the left of it can be changed too but at least one dot will be there. So phrase like:  `"asdsdf"` or `"dfg:dfgdfgfg"` can occur also.
I tried to use the following line of code but I got the first string after  the first accurance of the dots.

```
 g <- "fghh...eval.as.symbol.VarNum2.....SgY:ghhh"
 sapply(strsplit(g, split = "\\..."), "[", 2)
 [1] "eval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` to mark the end of a string and look for a group `(...)` of characters and colons `[A-Za-z:]` that occure at least one time `+`:

```
g <- c("fghh...eval.as.symbol.VarNum2.....SgY:ghhh", "fghh...eval.as.symbol.VarNum2.....SgYghhh")
sub(pattern="^.*\\.+([A-Za-z:]+)$", replacement="\\1", g)
# [1] "SgY:ghhh" "SgYghhh"
```

@DavidArenburg's solution to look for non-dot characters seems cleaner and smarter:

```
sub(pattern="^.*\\.+([^.]+)$", replacement="\\1", g)
# [1] "SgY:ghhh" "SgYghhh"
```

Comment: What if there is no `:` in the string? It seems like OP could have such type of strings

Comment: @DavidArenburg That doesn't matter. I add an example with missing `:`. `[A-Za-z:]` means that the character could be A-z and a colon but it is not necessary that all are present.

Comment: Yeah, right, this should work. But what happens if there is a comma for example? Or some other character?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I like your method to look for non-dot characters! I added it to my answer because you deleted yours.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.Can I ask what is the meaning of :replacement="\\1"

Comment: `\\1` refers to the first group (the first pair of parenthesis `(...)`). We simply replace the whole string with the matched group.